# CSS styles rendering incorrectly on Safari iOS (9.1)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari

### Problem Description

The CSS styles aren't applied correctly on Safari iOS (9.1).

What could be wrong? Or what could be missing?

In this project I used PDFJS inside an iframe to display PDF documents; bootstrap to make the application responsive and JavaScript to apply the class styles dynamically to some HTML elements.

I tried on recent desktop browsers like Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari (MAC OS X) and for Android devices as well and everything looks OK. When I try  in Safari (iOS) something goes wrong.

In Safari(iOS 9.1) the CSS styles are only applied to the elements if they are visible in the viewport area. It happens too when I switch the screen orientation.
The styles of html elements are set when the event pageRender of PDFJS is triggered.

### Initial HTML Page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div id="document-frame" class="document-container">
            <iframe id="pfdjs_frame" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;"></iframe>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

### IFrame HTML Page

```
<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint moznomarginboxes>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
       <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

### CSS Script

```
/**
* The default style for all fields.
*/
.DefaultStyle {
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color: #E9E9FF;
    border: 1px;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    background-size: contain;
 }
```